# How can i keep hidden div active when i reloading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have hidden section and when i click the button my section is opening but when im trying to reload my page or im going to another page my section is hiding. i want to keep it always opened to click the button and hide it.

Here is my html codes

```
<button class="btn btn-success advancedSearch">Advanced search</button>

<section id="search-banner" style="padding: 0px; ">
<div class="row">
    <div class="main-heading">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <h3>Advanced search</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center pb-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!--Header Text-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="{{ url('/advanced-search') }}" method="get">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <select name="categoryId" id="inputState1" class="form-control">
                                        <option></option>

                                            </optgroup>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <select name="cityId" id="inputState2" class="form-control">
                                        <option></option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <select name="salaryId" id="inputState3" class="form-control">
                                        <option></option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <select name="educationId" id="inputState4" class="form-control">
                                        <option></option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <select name="experienceId" id="inputState5" class="form-control">
                                        <option></option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button style="width: 100%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search-banner').hide();
    $('.advancedSearch').on('click', function () {
        $('#search-banner').fadeToggle();
    });

});
```

i need your help guys than you very much.

Comment: which section are you talking about. Are you talking about select fields? do you want them to be always visible or they should be visibe on button click

Answer (score 1):

try using localstorage function to store your last action.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* you need to replace page and advanced-search-page, but the logic is like this */
    if ( localStorage.getItem("banner_toggle") === null && page=='advanced-search-page') {
        $('#search-banner').hide();
    }
    $('.advancedSearch').on('click', function () {
        $('#search-banner').fadeToggle();
        if ( localStorage.getItem("banner_toggle") === null) {
             localStorage.setItem("banner_toggle", true);
        } else {
             localStorage.removeItem("banner_toggle");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer. your method is working but when im returning to main page my section is not closing.

Comment: i just want to keep this section always closed but when i click the button and when i going to advanced-search page activate this section.but when i going to home page or another page i want to keep hiding this section

Comment: you can add in the condition which page/s you want it to hide.. localstorage is like a cookie for javascript.. so just adjust it base on your preferences.

Comment: can u just update your code and show me it? i never use javascript cookie(

Comment: You need to adjust your question, and provide more info regarding what you wanted..

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this piece of code if you want it to be always visible and hide on click.

```
 $('#search-banner').fadeToggle();
```

jquerys toggle function toggles between showing and hiding elements. You can read more about this [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Now everytime you click on the button it will hide otherwise, it will remain open.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.advancedSearch').on('click', function () {
        $('#search-banner').fadeToggle();
       $('#search-banner').hide();
    });

});
```